# Ng-Repeat on Same Collection, used multiple times through an application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

This question has more to do with optimization/performance than anything else. Let's say I have an array of data

```
scope.array = [1,2,3,5,...,1000];
```

And I need to run ng-repeat over these elements like so:

```
<div class="table" ng-repeat="a in array"> {{a}} </div>
```

I'm actually not even sure the above is strictly accurate but it's irrelevant for the purpose of the question. Now lets say that that div is used in multiple places, maybe like so...

```
<div class="parent" ng-repeat="child in children">
    <div class="table" ng-repeat="a in array"> </div>
</div>
```

Every repetition of div.table is instantiating 1000 new scope elements, even though it's repeating over the same data set. If the data-binding is functionally one-way, i.e. the user can't actually manipulate the collection, what pattern allows you to prevent all of this redundant scope creation?

Comment: Do you want to prevent two-way data binding?

Comment: Not exactly. Even if I wanted data binding, is there a way to specify that each group of repeated elements should have the same scopes? I.e., if we have x groups of y repeated elements made using ng-repeat, there are only y scopes created, as opposed to x*y which seems to be the standard way.

Comment: ng-repeat will always create a new scope for each repeated element.  I don't think you can change that.  Angular isn't for every scenario and in this case where you need a nested loop of lists, maybe this is one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot avoid the creation of the child scopes, that is a critical part of how Angular works. Although the real issue here would be the total number of watches and not the creation of the scopes. The creations of the scope is a small once time operation however the watches live on for the life of the row.

For example take a table of 1,000 rows and 10 columns. Rendering the entire table would cause 10,000 watches to be created. That number of watches is not something any browser can cope with and will cause UI latency issue.

But why create rows and watches for elements that are not visible to the user?
That particular issue is not a new one and the solution is to use virtual buffering. There are existing Angular directives such as https://github.com/EnzeyNet/VirtualScroll and https://github.com/kamilkp/angular-vs-repeat that already do this for you.

The basic idea is that event if you have a data set of 100,000 you can only see N number on the screen at once, probably 10-40, so only render those rows that are in view.

Answer (score 0):

Points to consider:

1. Do not use $scope in your controller. Use controllerAs Controller/View syntax. [See the following best practice resource.](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#style-y030)
2. If you want one way binding, which is desirable if your data is only set once and doesn't update, use `::` syntax. Documentation can be found [here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/docs/guide/expression). For an explanation/example you can refer to [this blog](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/10/14/exploring-angular-1.3-one-time-bindings.html).